# How can I add a client-side (JavaScript) confirmation message box using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

How might I add a JavaScript message box with a confirmation option in ASP.NET?

Comment: http://bit.ly/2gzSS8 eh?

Answer (score 2):

Try using confirm :

```
<script>
    var userWantsToContinue = confirm("do you want to continue ?");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below uses client side messagebox and redirects to a page **test.aspx** only if textbox contain some value.

In **default.aspx**:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
<script>
function validate_this()

{

if (document.getElementById("TextBox1").value.length == 0)

{
return false;
}

else
{
return confirm('Do you wish to continue');
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick = "javascript:return validate_this();"/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In **default.aspx.vb**:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
            Response.Redirect("test.aspx")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript's confirm() method.

```
if(confirm('Are you sure?')) {
 // executed if the user clicks OK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing to add a confirm dialog box when the user clicks a button (such as a Delete button), where clicking Cancel has the effect of canceling a postback, you can use the Button control's **OnClientClick** property like so:

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('This will permanently delete this item. Are you sure you want to do this?');"
```

For more information on working with client-side script in an ASP.NET WebForms application, check out: [Client-Side Enhancements in ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020135953/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111506-1.aspx).