# C# for Confirm box when click on the button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, confirm

net MVC3.following is my view,

```
      @using (Html.BeginForm("InsertDetails", "Home"))
      {
         <h2 class="filter">Associate Details</h2>
     <fieldset class="fs">
     @foreach (var item in Model.lstTravelReadyEntities)
       {   
     <label class="Detail1" ><b>Associate Id : </b><input type="text" name="Aid" style="border-color:White;" value=@item.Var_AssoId ></label>
     <label class="Detail1"><b>Vertical :</b><input type="text" name="vertical" style="border-color:White;" value=@item.Var_Vertical ></label>
     <label class="Detail1"><b>Visa ValidFrom :</b><input type="text" name="vvf" style="border-color:White;" value=@item.Dt_VisaValidFrom > </label><br /><br />

     <label class="Detail2"><b>Associate Name :</b><input type="text" name="AsName" style="border-color:White;" value=@item.Var_AssociateName ></label>
     <label class="Detail2"><b>Account Name :</b><input type="text" name="Acname" style="border-color:White;" value=@item.Var_AccountName ></label>
     <label class="Detail2"><b>Visa ValidDate :</b><input type="text" name="vvt" style="border-color:White;" value=@item.Dt_VisaValidTill ></label><br /><br />

     <label class="Detail3"><b>Grade HR :</b><input type="text" name="gh" style="border-color:White;" value=@item.Var_Grade ></label>
     <label class="Detail3"><b>Project Name :</b><input type="text" name="Projname" style="border-color:White;" value=@item.Var_Project_Desc ></label><br />                   
     <label class="Detail3" style="visibility:hidden"><b>geo :</b><input type="text" name="geo" style="border-color:White;" value=@item.Var_Geo ></label><br />          
          }
         <h2> Response Details</h2><br />
         Supervisor Response :<input type="radio" class="radi" 
           name="radio" value="yes" onclick="javascript:Getfunc(this.value);">Yes
          <input type="radio" name="radio" value="no" 
           onclick="javascript:Getfunc(this.value)">No
           <div id="es"></div>
           <input type="submit" id="insert" value="Submit" name="Submit"/>
           </fieldset>
               }
```

And my following Controller,

```
          [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public string InsertDetails(FormCollection collection)
    {           
        TravelReadyModel oTravelReadyModel = new TravelReadyModel();
        string supervisorip =collection.Get("radio");
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(collection.Get("Aid"));
        string vertical = collection.Get("vertical");
        DateTime validfrom = Convert.ToDateTime(collection.Get("vvf"));
        string account = collection.Get("Acname");
        DateTime validtill = Convert.ToDateTime(collection.Get("vvt"));
        string grade = collection.Get("gh");
        string projectname = collection.Get("Projname");
        DateTime tdate = Convert.ToDateTime(collection.Get("date"));
        int commentid = 5;
        string comment = collection.Get("comment");
        string geo = collection.Get("geo");
        oTravelReadyModel.InsertTravelDetails(tdate, id, vertical, account, geo, validfrom, validtill, grade, projectname, supervisorip, commentid, comment);
        return "true";
    }
```

I want to get the innertext in the same page when the record has been inserted.what i have to return to get the success message in the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use plain old javascript in your submit button, so your code in your view will look like:

```
....
<input type="submit" id="insert" value="Submit" name="Submit" 
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit')">
</fieldset>
}
```

**Note:** There are other ways of doing this, but this is the quickest and simplest, and also the dirtiest.

Also see:

[How can I add a client-side (JavaScript) confirmation message box using ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713190/how-can-i-add-a-client-side-javascript-confirmation-message-box-using-asp-net)

for how to add it as validation.

Answer (score 0):

Can use the JQuery submit event. Check out the following link for N number of ways to do it.

http://api.jquery.com/submit/